# Making a table printed from an array by a loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a table using a loop but, the strings and numbers that make the table have different sizes so I can't a fixed size for the spaces. I can't just straight-up print the table because I'm specifically to use a loop to print it from the array.

The print statement looks like this:

```
case 2:
    System.out.println("Stock Name\t" + "Stock Symbol\t" + "Previous Closing Price\t "
                              "\t" + "Current Price\t" + "Change Percet\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println(stockNameList[i] + "\t" + stockSymbol[i] + PreviousClosingPrice[i] 
                            + "\t" + CurrentPrice[i] + "\t" + GetChangePercent(CurrentPrice, PreviousClosingPrice) + "\t");
```

and the output looks like this:

```
Stock Name  Stock Symbol    Previous Closing Price      Current Price   Change Percent  
Saudi Aramco    2222.SR30.91    35.85   -66.3013687133789   
SABIC   2010.SR89.29    88.8    -66.3013687133789   
Alinam Bank 1150.SR12.3 36.5    -66.3013687133789
```

what I want it to look like is like this:

```
Stock Name  Stock Symbol    Previous Closing Price      Current Price   Change Percent  
Saudi Aramco     2222.SR                30.91                  35.85            -66.3013687133789                   
SABIC            2010.SR                89.29                  88.8             -66.3013687133789   
Alinam Bank      1150.SR                12.3                   36.5             -66.3013687133789
```

I tried doing different print patterns but none of them seemed to work.
would appreciate any help.

Comment: How many parts of the output are incorrect?

Comment: sorry, the post doesn't look like I wanted it to. The spaces of the output are wrong, and the issue is the spaces vary, and i cannot custimize the spaces in each loop. so I would say the spaceses is the only wrong part of the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
package Tests;

public class st1 {
    public  static void main(String[] args) {
       String[] stockNameList = {"Saudi Aram","SAB","ALINAM BANK"};
       String[] stockSymbols = {"SR","ABC!!","A"};
       String[] previousClosingPrice = {"222.22","123456.55","1.00"};
      
       System.out.println(padString("STOCK NAME",20)+padString("Stock Symbol",20)
               +padString("PREVIOUS CLOSING PRICE",20));
     for(int i = 0 ; i < 3;i++)
     {
         System.out.println(padString(stockNameList[i],20)+padString(stockSymbols[i],20)
               +padString(previousClosingPrice[i],20));
     }
}
    public static String padString(String s, int len)
    {
       String formatString = "%-"+len+"s";
       return String.format(formatString, s);
    }
}
```